# DSpace - SolrCore Initialization Failures, Cannot create directory

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, dspace

I am getting 'Internal Server Error in Dspace JSPUI'. I think problem is with solr. I checked http://localhost:8080/solr/ . I found that solr is not able to create some directories with message "SolrCore Initialization Failures". The Dspace folder has all the permission for all the users. Log for one of the them is as follows:

`

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: /dspace/solr/search/data/index/write.lock
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:881)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:654)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:491)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:249)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /dspace/solr/search/data/index/write.lock
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock.obtain(NativeFSLockFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:77)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:755)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:77)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:64)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initIndex(SolrCore.java:531)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:785)
```

`

Comment: "Access Denied" usually means that the user that Solr runs under doesn't have write access to the directory where it's trying to create the file. Change ownership of the directory tree with `chown` (unless there's something special about your setup).

Comment: @MatsLindh , Thanks for the reply, the folder has all the permissions(w/r) for all the users. I already did that(chown and chmod).

Comment: In that case something else might hold the `write.lock` file. Are you running multiple instances from the same datadir? (i.e. another process has ownership of the lock)

Answer (score 0):

As the user running Dspace, do you get a permission error if you exec the following in a terminal?:

```
touch /dspace/solr/search/data/index/write.lock
```

If that's the case, this means that the user doesn't have permission to access the file.

Also, this is a lock file, which means that the index is being used probably by another Solr instance. Check that you don't have any other process using this file or solr.

You can also try to stop all instances of Dspace / Solr, delete the lock file manually and start the services again.

I strongly advise against giving full read - write permissions as this weakens security. Once you figure out the correct user and permissions for the file, restrict them correctly giving only read and / or write permissions to the users that need id (the solr and dspace user).